# Python logical operator precedence

Tags: python, operators, operator-precedence

Which operator takes precedence in `4 > 5 or 3 < 4 and 9 > 8`? Would this be evaluated to true or false?

I know that the statement `3 > 4 or (2 < 3 and 9 > 10)` should obviously evaluate to false but I am not quite sure how python would read `4 > 5 or 3 < 4 and 9 > 8`

Comment: Did you find the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) yet?

Comment: The first one is `True` because `3 < 4 and 9 > 8` is `True`.

Answer (score 2):

Comparisons are executed before `and`, which in turn comes before `or`. You can look up the precedence of each operator in the [expressions documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

So your expression is parsed as:

```
(4 > 5) or ((3 < 4) and (9 > 8))
```

Which comes down to:

```
False or (True and True)
```

which is `True`.